# How to create menus or links which are displayed only at the time of mouse hover on top of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image gallery with insert/replace/delete image  options available for users.
I have done displaying these options(REPLACE IMAGE and DELETE IMAGE) on the top of each images. and that options are displayed only when mouse hovering the particular image.

How to make the options appearing slowly when mouse hover

CSS

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    }


.toggle
{   font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;  
    right:0;

    padding:0px;
    width:100%;

    text-align:right;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    display:none;

}   


.toggle a
{   
    text-decoration:none;
     background:#000;
    padding:0;    
    font-size:10px;  
    color:white;
    line-height:100%;
    cursor:arrow;
}


.wrap:hover .toggle
{
    /*visibility:visible;  */
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="wrap">
<A name=1 href="image.php?imageid=<?php echo $imageid ?>&imageindex=<?php echo ((($page-1)*15)+$index-1) ;  ?> "><IMG  border=0 src="<?php echo $thumbpath; ?>" height="75" width="75" alt="<?php echo $caption ?>" title="<?php echo $caption ?>" ></A><BR>
<div class="toggle">
<?php
echo "<a href='delete.php?delete=yes&imageid=".$imageid.'&page='.$page."'>Delete </a>"
?>
<br>
<?php
echo "<a href='replace.php?update=yes&imageid=".$imageid.'&page='.$page."'>Replace </a>"
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none` and `position:absolute` properties to the div which needs to be toggled.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/d18eea9d28f3490b8dcbfa9e38f8336e.jpg" />
    <div class="toggle"><a href="#">REPLACE IMAGE</a> <a href="#"> DELETE IMAGE</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block
}
.toggle{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;  
    background:Black;
    padding:4px;
    width:100%;
    display:none
}
a{
    background:red;
    padding:2px;    
    font-size:12px;  
}
.wrap:hover .toggle{
    display:block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9SUR/1/)**

Comment: @Souwmya thanks its working, but i want it to be display on top right corner, also I want to use two images instead of the two text links.

Comment: @HYDERALI You can add anything inside the a tag. and for position you can write right:0

Comment: @Souwmya it can't be moved to right even with right:0